# JSON result with "0" name (zero name) - how can I create correct class in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON result from external server

```
{
    "address": {
        "0": {
            "name": "House 1",
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2
        }
    }
}
```

how can I create correct class in C# for parsing ?

I tried to get class here http://json2csharp.com
And then code

```
//first way
RootObject MyObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);
// another way
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(text);
```

But null pointer raise every time.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try *JContainer data = (JContainer)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);* that will return a JContainer what is a class which will allow you to access the data like in a dictionary.

Comment: Is there always *exactly* one address, always with the key "0"? It looks like you might want a dictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer here (in Stackoverflow)

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "0")]
public VJGeocenterSingle ZeroSingle { get; set; }
```

Excuse me for a newby question.
My first step in JSON :)